Headless OAuth2 Token Refresh Fails with Spring boot and MSAL4J
Edited the original question to provide a clearer overview and better understanding of the problem.
Thanks to @Steve Riesenberg and @Toerktumlare for guiding me in the right direction.
I developed a Kotlin-Spring Boot application that interacts with the Microsoft Graph API.
Users authenticate via a browser, after which scheduled background tasks run on their behalf.
These tasks require a seamless token refresh process.
While the initial token retrieval worked, I encountered issues when trying to refresh the token during these scheduled tasks in a headless (non-interactive) environment.
My primary goal was to ensure that token refreshes worked reliably without user interaction.
I’ve provided one way to handle this in my own answer below, which I marked as accepted.

Unfortunately, there look to be quite a few things wrong in this code such as non-thread safe access (e.g. graphComponent.set...). Also, you say you are operating in a background thread, but instead you show a controller endpoint. It seems as though you are hoping to have a user authorize a client, and then continue to use their access token in the background? Typically, background threads would use the client_credentials grant and not a user's access/refresh token with authorization_code. Please clarify what you are trying to do and why and show all related code.

Thank you for the feedback! User authentication is essential here, as the app performs actions on behalf of each user in Microsoft Graph, like accessing their To-Do lists.
Once authorized, background tasks sync and update user-specific data. Therefore, I need to refresh the access token to continue, even when the user is offline.
I handle initial user authorization via a controller endpoint, then use background processes for token refresh and data sync. Any tips on ensuring thread safety with this approach would be appreciated! Thanks again!

Unfortunately, it is quite difficult to know what is wrong because you have only provided the information "the renewClient is always null" and very little else. It would be helpful to provide logs, Spring Security configuration, yaml or properties (if any), and probably more details. I also don't know what you're using the azure and microsoft dependencies for so I can't be sure if they have any relevance since you don't seem to be using them in the code snippets you've provided. Your code is also quite incorrect, so the best I could do is provide a sketch of a better starting point.

Having said that, I see you have provided some properties from spring.cloud.azure. I don't know what MSAL4J is for, but it seems possible you are mixing libraries. Since you are using Spring Security's OAuth2 Client library to obtain an access token, what are you intending to use MSAL4J for?

If I understand correctly, MSAL4J handles OAuth2 authentication, so additional configuration shouldn’t be needed. All settings are in application.yml under spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.
Currently, GraphRestAuth works fine. We have data access, and both OAuth2AuthenticationToken and OAuth2AuthorizedClient are available, with oauthClient containing an accessToken and refreshToken.
However, I’m unsure why the token refresh fails in getGraphService. I’ve added three images for clarity. Let me know if more information is needed. Thanks for the help!

I have provided a better starting point in an answer. Please change your incorrect code to start with what I provided and go from there. I can't tell anything new from your images.

as Steve pointed out, you are mixing 2 ways of fetching tokens. MSAL4J is a library for fetching tokens, ONLY. It does something that spring security already does. So i have no idea why you have chosen to use both of these libraries that do the same thing. This is clearly stated in their docs. You either choose to use one or the other, or you use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory-developer-guide?tabs=SpringCloudAzure4x you dont mix and match both spring oauth2 and microsofts library. Good luck

Most guides and examples online were for older versions of the Microsoft Graph SDK and didn’t work with MSAL4J 6.x. It took me a while to find the upgrade guide.
There are quite a few ways to authenticate, which can be confusing. I had to figure out which authentication provider suited my needs. Microsoft Graph authentication provider
Here’s one approach that worked for me.
First of all, i just need microsoft-graph and msal4j (Thanks to @Steve Riesenberg and @Toerktumlare)
build.gradle
...
implementation("com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph:6.20.0")
implementation("com.microsoft.azure:msal4j:1.17.2")
...

I used the "Authorization Code Flow" for the initial login via the browser. The "Confidential Client Application" was used to store and renew the token.
Rest Endpoints for initial authentication via browser:
@RestController
class GraphRestAuth(
    val config: TaskControllerConfig,
    val graphAuthProvider: GraphWebAuthProvider
) {
    @GetMapping("/", "/login")
    fun login(): ResponseEntity<Any> {
        val authUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize" +
                "?client_id=XXX" +
                "&response_type=code" +
                "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/redirect" +
                "&response_mode=query" +
                "&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND).header(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, authUrl).build()
    }

    @GetMapping("/redirect")
    fun handleRedirect(@RequestParam code: String): String {
        val graphClient = graphAuthProvider.initializeWithAuthCode(code)
        val user = graphClient.me().get()
        return "Hello, ${user.displayName}!"
    }
}

Handle token and caching:
@Component
class GraphWebAuthProvider(
    val config: TaskControllerConfig
) {
    private var tokenExpireDate: OffsetDateTime? = null
    private var graphClient: GraphServiceClient? = null

    fun initializeWithAuthCode(authCode: String): GraphServiceClient {
        val tokenCacheAspect = TokenCacheAspect("/app-config/tokenCache.json")
        val clientCredential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret("XXX")

        val cca = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder("XXX", clientCredential)
            .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common")
            .setTokenCacheAccessAspect(tokenCacheAspect)
            .build()

        val parameters = AuthorizationCodeParameters.builder(
            authCode, URI.create("http://localhost:8080/redirect")
        ).scopes(setOf("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default")).build()

        val result = cca.acquireToken(parameters).join()
        tokenExpireDate = result.expiresOnDate().toInstant().atOffset(OffsetDateTime.now().offset)

        val tokenCredential = SimpleTokenCredential(result.accessToken())
        graphClient = GraphServiceClient(tokenCredential)
        return graphClient!!
    }

    fun refreshAccessToken() {
        val tokenCacheAspect = TokenCacheAspect("/app-config/tokenCache.json")
        val clientCredential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret("XXX")

        val cca = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder("XXX", clientCredential)
            .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common")
            .setTokenCacheAccessAspect(tokenCacheAspect)
            .build()

        val accountsInCache = cca.accounts.join()
        val account = accountsInCache.first()
            ?: throw RuntimeException("No account in cache found.")

        try {
            val silentParameters = SilentParameters.builder(setOf("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read", "https://graph.microsoft.com/Tasks.Read", "https://graph.microsoft.com/Tasks.ReadWrite", "offline_access"), account).build()
            val result = cca.acquireTokenSilently(silentParameters).join()
            tokenExpireDate = result.expiresOnDate().toInstant().atOffset(OffsetDateTime.now().offset)

            val tokenCredential = SimpleTokenCredential(result.accessToken())
            graphClient = GraphServiceClient(tokenCredential)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            logger.error("Error in token refresh: ${ex.message}", ex)
        }
    }

    fun getGraphService(): GraphServiceClient {
        if (tokenExpireDate!!.isBefore(OffsetDateTime.now())) {
            refreshAccessToken()
        }
        return graphClient ?: throw IllegalStateException("GraphServiceClient could not be initialized.")
    }
}


After the app starts, the user logs in via localhost:8080/ and authenticates. Once logged in, the getGraphService method can be called anytime to obtain a valid GraphService and perform background tasks.

As a starting point, please consider the following sketch which may provide a better starting point for what you are trying to do. Please note that I have not tested this code and have not used Microsoft Graph API, it is just a (hopefully valuable) starting point.
Just to be sure you have configured Spring Security correctly, you need the following at a minimum:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration {
  @Bean
  fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    http {
      authorizeHttpRequests {
        authorize(anyRequest, authenticated)
      }
      oauth2Login { }
      oauth2Client { }
    }

    return http.build()
  }
}

You will also need configuration properties (yaml) for the graph client like the example Access Protected Resources in the reference.
Next, the endpoint you use to authorize a client will internally store the access/refresh token automatically using an OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository. To do this, you can inject a DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager provided as a @Bean by Spring Security (you don't have to create one yourself) for use within a Servlet context. There are various ways to pass the access token to the Microsoft API including the way you demonstrated, but I would recommend skipping the @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient and use the provided ExchangeFilterFunction instead. Something like this:
@RestController
class GraphRestAuth(
    authorizedClientManager: OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager,
    webClientBuilder: WebClient.Builder
) {
    private val oauth2 = ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
        authorizedClientManager)
    private val webClient = webClientBuilder
        .baseUrl("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0")
        .apply(oauth2.oauth2Configuration())
        .build()

    @GetMapping("/signIn")
    fun signIn(authentication: Authentication): ToDoListResponse {
        println("Retrieving todos for ${authentication.name}")
        return webClient.get()
            .uri("/me/todo/lists")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ToDoListResponse::class.java)
            .block()!!
    }
}

Note that it is incorrect to attempt to store the authorizedClient obtained from the authorized client manager yourself. As I mentioned above, it is stored automatically by the framework using an OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.
Next, you are correct that you can attempt to obtain/refresh the access token from a background thread (via @Scheduled) using an @Service (similar to @Component) by constructing an AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.
@Service
class GraphService(
    clientRegistrationRepository: ClientRegistrationRepository,
    authorizedClientService: OAuth2AuthorizedClientService
) {
    private val authorizedClientManager =
        AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService)
            .apply {
                val authorizedClientProvider = OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                    .refreshToken()
                    .build()
                setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider)
            }

    fun getGraphService(principalName: String): GraphServiceClient {
        val authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("graph")
            .principal(principalName)
            .build()
        val renewedClient = authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest)
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("No access token available")
        // ...

        return GraphServiceClient(...)
    }
}

Note that you MUST find a way to pass in the username, you SHOULD NOT directly reference an authorizedClient here, as it must be obtained from the OAuth2AuthorizedClientService. This is likely what was causing renewedClient to be null in your code.

I'm encountering a 401 Unauthorized error.

I'm encountering a 401 Unauthorized error when i try to login
In your code, I don’t see tokenValue in the headers. Is this handled differently by ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction?
I used .defaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${oauthClient.accessToken.tokenValue}") in webClientBuilder.
So i needed @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("graph") oauthClient: OAuth2AuthorizedClient? to inject oauthClient.
This was the only way I could get authorization to work.
Could the missing explicit Authorization header be the reason for this, or am I missing an additional configuration?

You are likely missing something, but again you haven't provided your entire configuration in your question. I can't speak for what you're trying to do with spring.cloud.azure properties but you are mixing up your libraries and I don't know how you have anything working in your original attempt. Since you're using dependencies that are not Spring Security dependencies, I cannot help you troubleshoot those, my apologies.

I’ve included all my configuration details in the original post, and I’m not sure what else you might need.
As for MSAL4J, I think it handles the authentication alongside Spring Security. Here’s more info on MSAL4J: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/java/
Thanks for your help.
I hope someone can jump in and provide further clarification.

"I think it handles the authentication alongside Spring Security." These libraries have the same/overlapping uses. I suggest picking one, as you will have an easier time understanding things. "I’ve included all my configuration details in the original post" You have not shown your Spring Security configuration. See my answer which shows one. Please read the OAuth2 chapters of the reference docs to get further clarity.
